# difference between n and size parameters in np.random.binomial(n,p, size = 1000)

Tags: numpy, statistics

I couldnt understand the difference between n and size parameters in np.random.binomial.

```
N = 1200
p =0.53
q = 1000

np.random.binomial(N, p, size = q) 
np.random.binomial(1, p, size = q)
np.random.binomial(N,p, size= q)
```

N is the number of trials, but is what is the size doing in the above formula. also kindly explain the vabove three versions of binomials.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. np.random.binomial(N, p, size = q)
2. np.random.binomial(1, p, size = q)
3. np.random.binomial(N,p, size= q)

1st and 3rd are similar, i can see. These two are binomial random number generator

And, 2nd one is bernoulli random number generator

---

Explanation of binomial:

A binomial random variable counts how often a particular event occurs in a fixed number of tries or trials.

Here,

- n = number of trials
- p = probability event of interest occurs on any one trial
- size = number of times you want to run this experiment

Suppose, You wanna check how many times you will get six if you roll dice 10 times. 
Here,

- n = 10,
- p = (1/6)  # probability of getting six in each roll

But, You have to do this experiment multiple times.

Let, 
In 1st experiment,  you get 3 six

In 2nd expwriment, you get 2 six

In 3rd experiment, you get 2 six

In Pth experiment, you get 2 six, here P is the size

---

Explanation of bernoulli:

Suppose you perform an experiment with two possible outcomes: either success or failure. Success happens with probability  p, while failure happens with probability  1-p. A random variable that takes value  1 in case of success and 0 in case of failure is called a Bernoulli random variable.

Here,

- n = 1, Because you need to check whether it is success or failure one time
- p = probability of success
- size = number of times you will check this

---

You can also read this, [numpy.random.binomial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html)

Also, [Difference between Binomial and Bernoulli](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~babu/418dist/binom.html)

[image]

Comment: return [np.mean(np.random.binomial(1, p, size = N)) for x in xrange(M)] , In this example if M = 18 polls, p = 0.53, N = 1200. I get a vector of  zeros and ones, of length 1200. But if I do np.random.binomial(N, p, size =1), I get a single array value ([652]). This is where I am confused.

Comment: In 1st case, 1200 size array.. from 1st 18 element, number of 1 is equal to 1st element of your 2nd case.. right?

Comment: let, m= 10, (1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0) -> this is your 1st case.. In 2nd case, number of 1 from each slot of size 10 is actual result..

Comment: Actually, binomial is summation of bernoulli trails.

Comment: In this case : np.random.binomial(1, p, size =N). Where N = 1200, As per understanding I am generating random 0s and 1s 1200 times. I am doing it 18 times(M value). I am I right??

Answer (score 7):

`n` and `p` describe the distribution itself. `size` gives the number (and shape) of results. Best illustrated with this example from the manual:

```
>>> n, p = 10, .5 # number of trials, probability of each trial
>>> s = np.random.binomial(n, p, 1000)
# result of flipping a coin 10 times, tested 1000 times.
```

You will get a 1000-number vector, each number being from (10, 0.5) binomial distribution.

Answer (score 4):

n = trials in one experiment;
size = how many time you want to perform this experiment

**Why we need size?** To achieve accuracy in our prediction. As you know more experiment mean more data we have. Still confused? Don't worry, let me explain with some detail and example.

---

**For example:**
I want to know how many chances of head occuring 4 times, if I toss a coin 10 times. Now if I only toss a coin 10 times, maybe head occurs 7 or 2 , or 5 times, so for accurate results I have to perform this  experiment many time so that I have a huge data set of results from which I can know my accurate result.

In this binomial prediction, I am telling `random.binomial`, to do 1000 (size) times experiment and in each experiment do 10 trials (n) and chances for success(p) of each trial i.e. getting a head is 1/2 = 0.5 (50%).

```py
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(random.binomial(n=10, p=0.5, size=1000), hist=True, kde=True)
```

---

Now you can see in the [following graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvYx7.png), the chances of success that 5 time head of coin will occur is 0.6 (60%), 4 time will head occur is 50% and so on. x-axis shows the 'value'  and y-axis shows the 'successful chances of that value'.

Answer (score 1):

For a visual example, consider the following plot

[image]

The range of possible values in this distribution appears to be a set of integers containing (0, 1, 2).
0 represents the number of times there were no successes given two trials.
1 represents the number of times there was 50% success given two trials, meaning where only one out of the two succeeded. And 2 represents the number of times all the trials succeeded which in this case we see that about 250 times 2/2 trials have succeeded.

The amount of times that the number 1 has appeared seems to be the highest as indicated on the y-axis of the plot, it is about 500. The x-axis represents possible outcomes, and the total amount of tests is 1000 when we add up the bar heights of 1, 2, 3 respectively. What this means is that given several trials, and a probability of all those trials occurring, we can then plot the distribution like so.

Because in this case the number of trials is 2 and out of all of the 2 trials there is a 50% chance of each trial happening so in order to get all trials successful that means that you would need trial #1 and #2 to be successful which is 25% because P(Trial) = .5 and P(Trial)*P(Trial) = .25 or 25%. To get no successes out of all the trials you would also only get that result 25% of the times tested.
What we are left with is that 50% of the trials will succeed and 50% will not.
That is denoted by the 1 in the plot above. In other words 500 out of 1000 times, we had 2 trials and only one of those 2 trials succeeded, which gave us 500 successes as 500/1000 = 1/2.

Now I can show you the code for this plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

distro = np.random.binomial(2, .5, 1000)
plt.hist(distro, 100)
```

This is essentially saying, "Create for me a distribution such that I will have 2 trials where the probability of the success of each trial is 50%, and run one thousand cases" - The cases aren't the trials. You could technically put in 100 into the first parameter and that wouldn't change the general picture of the distribution, what would change is the density or range of values i.e the number of bars in the plot but it would follow the same distribution.

Another example:

[image]

What do you think the number of trials is in this case?

The answer is about 10, as we can see on the x-axis there are about 10 trials and it seems that the probability distribution isn't 50%.

What do you think the number of times we tested this scenario?

The answer is 100, if you add up all the bar heights it would come out to exactly 100.

It turns out that indeed the probability distribution for the second plot is also 50% which would mean that we should get an even distribution, i.e getting 5/10 trials would be 50%, 4/10 and 6/10 would both have a 40% chance, 3/10 and 7/10 would both have a 30% chance, 2/10 and 8/10 would both have a 20% chance and so on and so forth. But the reason we don't see that distribution to be even is that the number of tests was limited to only 100. Here is the same probability distribution but just a higher number of tests let's say 10,000.

As you can see we get an even distribution that follows very much our probability function, which is that overall 5 out of the 10 trials should success which means a 50% chance of success out of 10 trials, tested 10,000 times gives us the desired result.

So to sum up, all the images have the same probability distribution it's just that we can see it more clearly when the number of test cases is increased which is the total sum of the bar heights. And increasing the number of trials just allows for a potentially larger breadth of outcomes of bars but the relative probability stays the same as we saw that in the first plot, the probability of getting 1 out of 2 trials is the same as the last image where we get 5 out of the 10 successes.

Answer (score 1):

This function is only for binomial outcomes. This function returns the number of successes. Success represents one of the 2 outcomes of the event. Either output could be a success. For sake of understanding, let us say, Heads is the success.

**CASE 1: Suppose you want to flip a fair coin 1 time.**

Here n = 1 (as we flipped a coin),

p = 0.5 (fair coin has 0.5 probability for each side, heads or tails), and

size = 1 (We want to flip this coin once)

Number of outcomes = n*size = 1

```
np.random.binomial(n = 1, p = 0.5 , size = 1)
```

Output:

```
array([1])
```

This output means, that there was one success. This implies we got Heads as an outcome.

**CASE 2: Suppose you want to flip a fair coin 2 times.**

Here n = 1 (as we flipped a coin),

p = 0.5 (fair coin has 0.5 probability for each side, heads or tails), and

size = 2 (We want to flip this coin once)

Number of outcomes = n*size = 2

```
np.random.binomial(n = 1, p = 0.5 , size = 2)
```

Output:

```
array([1, 0])
```

There was one success and one failure. i.e; First we got Heads and then Tails. Here the count of success in the output array of each event. Again, either output could be a success.

**CASE 3: Suppose you want to flip 3 fair coins 15 times.**

Here n = 3 (as we flipped 3 coins),

p = 0.5 ,

size = 15 (We want to flip 3 coins, 15 times)

Number of outcomes = n*size = 45

```
np.random.binomial(n = 3, p = 0.5 , size = 15)
```

Output:

```
array([1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

In the output,

The first element means there were 1 Head & 2 Tails

The second element means there were 0 Head & 3 Tails

The third element means there were 0 Head & 3 Tails

The fourth element means there were 3 Heads & 0 Tail

................

The last element means there were 0 Head & 3 Tails

Answer (score 0):

In probability theory and statistics, the binomial distribution with parameters n and p is the discrete probability distribution of the number of successes **( which is output of the function, np.random.binomial when tested 1 time)** in a sequence of n independent experiments **( which is n in your formlula)**, each asking a yes–no question, and each with its own boolean-valued outcome: success/yes/true/one (with probability p) or failure/no/false/zero (with probability q = 1 − p).
  Test is nothing but how many time we want to run this experiment, test=10 would generate 10 output- ( all represents different 'no of time getting yes')